# Is there a way to print expanded macro or way to debug macro

Tags: system-verilog

In case of systemverilog is there a way to print expanded macro? Or is there a way to debug macro?

I would avoid macros as much as I could but in this case I can't.

Comment: Both answers to the question are correct, since the behavior is tool specific instead of language specific.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be tool specific. In Questa/Modelsim, there is a `vlog -Edebug` switch to get the expanded pre-processor output.

Comment: Thanks I've Questa (which is working correctly) so was looking for Incisive mainly. I'm going to try Questa option just to make sure though.

Answer (score 1):

In Incisive Simulator you can use the `-linedebug` flag and open the file in Source Browser. There you can expand and debug macros.

Comment: Thanks, turns out its a bug in Cadence tool